# EasyNetQ publish and consume

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, easynetq

I am new to EasyNetQ and RabbitMQ.Unfortunately I am having problem with consuming messages and I am not sure if its because I am doing the Publish wrong or either my consuming is not correct. I can see by publishing, it does send to queue and consuming it does take it off from the queue. However when message is returned I get null :S
I am using **IAdvancedBus**

Code Snippet for Publishing:

```
public void send(RegistrationCreatedEvent obj )
{
   MessageBus.Publish(Exchange, RoutingKey, true, new Message<RegistrationCreatedEvent>(obj));
}
```

Code Snippet for Consuming:

```
public void Receive()
{
  MessageBus.Consume(Queue, (messageBody, properties, info) => Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    var stringMessage = Encoding.Default.GetString(messageBody);

    json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RegistrationCreatedEvent>(stringMessage);
                Console.WriteLine($"Message Received:  {json}");
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you tell us which variable is null? If `messageBody` is already null you may have a problem in publishing. Then I would recommend that you stop your consumer, send a message to the queue and go have a look at the messages with the management plugin https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

And since you want your message deserialized anyway i would recommend to use the built in messageSerializer instead of doing it by yourself. Would look something like this:

```
bus.Consume(queue, x => x.Add<RegistrationCreatedEvent>((message, info) => 
{
  //do something with message.body
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was keeping my model class property public rather than private.